# SocketCAN c++ wrapper

Tags: c++, linux, wrapper, socketcan

We want to use [SocketCan](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/can.txt) in a Linux application programmed in C++.
Does anyone know a nice C++ wrapper for SocketCan?
Otherwise I will write something.

Comment: Why would you need a wrapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far I haven't seen any dedicated C++ wrapper for SocketCAN, but [qcanalyzer](http://ortcan.sourceforge.net/qcanalyzer/) provides one for Qt. See this [feature request](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-31058) for more details.

**Update**: Qt provides [CAN support](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qtcanbus-backends.html) beginning with Qt 5.6.